# R [raster] : How to use a raster layer to determine transparency of another layer?

Tags: r, plot, raster, alpha-transparency

Let us assume that I have two raster layers, one of the estimated abundance of a given species in a given area, and another one with some measure of uncertainty of the estimations. To keep things simple I use a very simplified example, yielding the two maps below (left: abundance, right: uncertainty).

```
library(raster)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 5.1))
abund <- matrix(1:16, 4)
abund.r <- raster(abund)
plot(abund.r, col = colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"), space = "rgb")(16))
uncert <- matrix(c(rep(0.2, 8), rep(0.8, 8)), 4, byrow = TRUE)
uncert.r <- raster(uncert)    
plot(uncert.r)
```

[image: Example maps for the given code]

In this example, the estimations in the northern part of the area are less certain than those in the south. I am looking for a possibility to combine abundance and uncertainty in a single map. I'd like to visualize uncertainty by using the same colours as in the left map and by modifying the transparency of each cell in the grid according to the uncertainty value in the right map. Consequently, abundance estimates in the northern part should be more transparent (less certain) than the estimates in the south (more certain). However, the alpha argument accepts only a single value, for example:

```
plot(MAT1.r, col = colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"), space = "rgb")(16),
     alpha = 0.5)
```

When I try to use a vector, only its first element is used.

My question: How can I use the information from the uncertainty map to modify transparency in the abundance map? Any hint towards a solution or advice for an alternative approach is highly appreciated.

Comment: Two thoughts. 1) `plot` the lower half with `alpha=1` and then set `par(new=TRUE)` and `plot` the upper half (with coordinates set appropriately) with `alpha=.5` .  2) Convert your raster numerical data to octal colors, e.g.  `#FF0000`  and add two trailing digits which define the transparency, e.g.  `FF000088` is 50%

Comment: @user7417 Do you still need an answer for this or did you already figure it out? I could help here I think..

Comment: @Shekeine: I found chapter 5.6.1 'Visualization of uncertainty' in Tom Hengl's book 'A Practical Guide to Geostatistical Mapping' (ISBN 978-90-9024981-0) and applied a technique he called 'whitening'. Alternative approaches, however, are highly welcome....I'm eager to see which suggestions you have!

Answer (score 3):

`ggplot2` is incredibly resourceful whenever you want to go the extra mile with data visualization. Consider this:

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

abund.r <- raster(matrix(1:16, 4))
uncert.r <- raster(matrix(c(rep(0.2, 8), rep(0.8, 8)), 4, byrow=T))

#Layer the two rasters into one multi-band raster for easier manipulation
abu_unc <- stack(abund.r, uncert.r)

#Get cell positions in cartesian coordinates for each cell
coords <- xyFromCell(object=abu_unc, cell=1:ncell(abu_unc))

#abu_unc is a 2 layer raster where band 1==abundance and band 2==uncertainty
#Convert abu_unc () to a dataframe
abu_unc_df <- as.data.frame(abu_unc)

#Add cell coordinates 
dat <- data.frame(coords, abu_unc_df)
colnames(dat) <- c("x", "y","Abundance", "Uncertainty")

#Plot dat, where the fill is abundance and transparency (alpha), is the respective uncertainty value
mymap <- ggplot(data=dat) + theme_bw() + coord_equal() +
 geom_raster(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=Abundance, alpha=Uncertainty)) +

  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.4, 1), breaks=seq(0.4, 1, 0.1))+
  scale_fill_gradient2(mid="yellow", high = "darkgreen")+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0.01,0.01)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.01,0.01)) +

  #General aesthetics
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=12),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=12, angle=90),
    axis.text = element_text(size=10),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
    print(mymap)

#Save plot to file
    ggsave(filename = "mymap.png", plot= mymap, dpi=300)
```

Note the usage of:

- `scale_fill_gradient2()` to customize the abundance fill
- `scale_alpha_continous()` for the uncertainty transparency

You can fiddle with the two to get the graph to look as you deem most appropriate for your data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of 'raster', you can use a vector or a RasterLayer to set transparency (alpha)

```
library(raster)
abund.r <- raster(matrix(1:16, 4))
uncert.r <- raster(matrix(c(rep(0.2, 8), rep(0.8, 8)), 4, byrow = TRUE))    

plot(abund.r, col=colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"), space="rgb")(16), alpha=uncert.r)
```